# How to use `less` as default pager for `--help`?

Tags: debian, less, lxde, help-files, pager

I use `--help` option a lot. It's annoying how it jumps to the end with help. It can be done with `|less` option. I want `|less` to be my default option. Can I use less as default paging for `--help`?

I use Debian Jessie with LXDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior of `--help` depends on a program and not the shell. So `| less` is the easiest option.

`less` is built in `man` and `info`.